# strings get changed just after refresh on i18next

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-i18next

I'm using the latest i18next (react)
I've created 2 buttons for 2 different languages, when I hit one of them, nothing happened..
just realized, when I hit refresh button I see the strings changed on my website..

here is my i18n.js file:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

import translationEN from '../locals/en/translation.json';
import translationPT from '../locals/pt/translation.json';

// the translations
const resources = {
    en: {
        translation: translationEN
    },
    pt: {
        translation: translationPT
    },
};
i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources,
        fallbackLng: "en"
    });

export default i18n;
```

on App.js, I'm using:

```
const changeLanguage = (ln) => {
    return () => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(ln);
    }
};
```

on render():

```
<div>
  <button className="langBtn" onClick={changeLanguage('en')}>EN</button>
  <button className="langBtn" onClick={changeLanguage('pt')}>PT</button>
</div>
```

I'm using the translate by the following:

```
import i18n from "./config/i18n";
{i18n.t('HomePageHeader')}
```

Thanks for the help..

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your resources are not statics, I think that you should be using something like that:

```
const { i18n } = useTranslation()

const toggleLang = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  // overly simplistic way of toggling between languages
  if (Object.values(SupportedLngs).includes(value)) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(value)
  }
}
```

The supportedLngs should be something like this:

```
const SupportedLngs = {
  en: 'en',
  es: 'es',
  'pt-BR': 'pt-BR',
  pt: 'pt',
}
```

Button HTML:

```
{Object.values(SupportedLngs)?.map(lng => (
          <button
            key={lng}
            style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: 99999 }}
            type="button"
            value={lng}
            onClick={toggleLang}
          >
            {lng}
          </button>
        ))}
```

That's because you're trying to use i18n from your config file and it doesn't trigger any rerender in your app